# How does one get a list of pending Comments that are addressed to you in an Excel Spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, comments

I use Microsoft Office 365 / Microsoft Excel at work and to communicate the other team members and myself often make use of the comments feature.

But the comments feature is a little bit crap, in that it doesn't let you send one email with links to all the comments, but instead is sends one email for each comment.

Is there a feature where you can:

1. Write all your comments.
2. Select which comments you want to add to the email for each user.
3. Send an email with just those comments.

Or is there a way I can copy links to just that cell and paste them into an email without sending an email each time I tag someone?

The comments are great, but the workflow as it is now is absolutely terrible.